# ASP.NET: RegisterClientScriptInclude

Tags: asp.net, scripting

I have a page that calls RegisterClientScriptInclude. For some reason, the script isn't included though. If I change it to RegisterStartupScript or RegisterClientScriptBlock, the script isn't written to the markup either.

Why might this be? Are there certain preconditions that may preclude a client script from being registered?

Comment: can you post some codes?

Answer (score 4):

Are you using Ajax? If you're using MS Ajax, you should be using the `ScriptManager.Register....()` methods.

If you're using straight webforms, you should be using the `ClientScriptManager.Register....()` methods.